# cmake 3.12 version installation on RHEL 7

Tags: cmake

I had cmake 3.9 version on my RHEL 7.6 system. But for some development work, i need 3.12 version.
I  downloaded the https://cmake.org/files/v3.12/cmake-3.12.2.tar.gz. Untarred the tar file and
Executed the commands trying to install it. But I am getting errors in each of the below case.
Can anyone please let me know if you have any idea to fix it and get the latest version?

1st trial

```
./bootstrap --prefix=$HOME
make;make install
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:82 (file):
  file failed to open for writing (Permission denied):
/workspace/poomanju/_cmake_build/cmake-3.12.2/install_manifest.txt
```

2nd trial

```
./bootstrap
make;make install.
```

3rd trial

```
./configure
make;make install
```

I tried the command being root. It seems the installation completes successfully. But when I come out of root privilege and view the version as regular user, I see the version is still 3.9.

```
bash-4.2$ /usr/local/bin/cmake --version
cmake version 3.12.2
CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).

bash-4.2$ which cmake
/usr/local/bin/cmake

bash-4.2$ cmake --version
CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT !!!
CMake has most likely not been installed correctly.
Modules directory not found in
/usr/local/share/cmake-3.9
cmake version 3.9.6
CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

Comment: You show 3 attempts, but which **exact** attempt you have used when finally install CMake (with `sudo`)?

Comment: exact attempt you have used when finally install CMake:- i used the 1st one

Comment: So you install `cmake` under `$HOME` prefix, which is like `/home/me`. Why do you use CMake from `/usr/local/bin/cmake` for check that installation?

Comment: If you're upgrading anyway, upgrade to the _latest_ version.